# Typing issue when querying children using Supabase-js

Tags: typescript, supabase

I have the following generated (from supabase-cli) type for my `collections` table:

```
export interface Database {
  public: {
    Tables: {
      collections: {
        Row: {
          created_at: string
          description: string | null
          id: string
          parent_id: string | null
          short_title: string | null
          title: string | null
          website: string | null
        }
        Insert: {
          created_at?: string
          description?: string | null
          id?: string
          parent_id?: string | null
          short_title?: string | null
          title?: string | null
          website?: string | null
        }
        Update: {
          created_at?: string
          description?: string | null
          id?: string
          parent_id?: string | null
          short_title?: string | null
          title?: string | null
          website?: string | null
        }
        Relationships: [
          {
            foreignKeyName: "collections_parent_id_fkey"
            columns: ["parent_id"]
            isOneToOne: false
            referencedRelation: "collections"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          }
        ]
      }
    // and so on
```

The table is defined as such in SQL:

```sql
create table
  public.collections (
    id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid (),
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    title text null,
    description text null,
    short_title text null,
    website text null,
    parent_id uuid null,
    constraint collections_pkey1 primary key (id),
    constraint collections_parent_id_fkey foreign key (parent_id) references collections (id) on update cascade on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

I'm grabbing a particular collection like so:

```
    const { data: collection } = await supabase
        .from('collections')
        .select(`*, collections(*)`)
        .eq(`id`, params.id)
        .single()
```

And this is the typing that's been inferred:

```
const collection: {
    created_at: string;
    description: string | null;
    id: string;
    parent_id: string | null;
    short_title: string | null;
    title: string | null;
    website: string | null;
    collections: {
        created_at: string;
        ... 5 more ...;
        website: string | null;
    } | null;
} | null
```

In particular, `collections` is typed as an object, but should be typed as an array of objects (which is what actually is built). Any clues on what I've done wrong or how to fix things?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Is the referenced `collections` not supposed to be a single object?

Comment: It should be an array containing each collection whose parent_id points to the collection. That's what Supabase provides, but the typing is mistaken.

Comment: Would you be able to share your table definition as well? There is a chance that it's a bug on the Supabase SDK too, but want to double check.

Comment: I've added it to the post

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with the table definition. Looking at your table definition, each collection has a single parent collection, so the type definition that Supabase has is correct. Why do you think each collection should have array of parents?

Comment: It shouldn't. Supabase returns an array of children as it should, but the typing is an object, not an array.

Comment: Each collection only has a single parent defined by the `parent_id` column, and therefore should only have a single parent. In what circumstance would a collection have multiple parents?

Comment: Ah, okay if you look at it from the parent's perspective, it has many children.